# Keras getting frozen when using regularizer in CNN model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I had a custom CNN implementation in keras running with TensorFlow backend. To improve generalizability I was working on adding regularization to the CNN model. The model works fine without any activity/kernel regularization. The moment I add an activity/kernel regularization the model freezes in between; training typically stops in between batches/iterations of a single epoch (for e.g. 67/172 batch). The issue is very repeatable and reproducible on my system and I was able to localize the issue to the implementation of regularization. It was strange to see this behavior and I could not find similar issues by others. I am not sure if I need to provide any additional information, if someone can guide me on what is lacking, I would be more than happy to provide the required information, and guidance on the issue would be greatly appreciated.

The following are some helpful information about things like the libraries/dependencies

1. Keras 2.4.3
2. Tensorflow 2.3.1
3. GPU: NVIDIA 1070 TI (8GB)
4. cudart64_101.dll was successfully openedT
5. The code was written in Spyder running on Python 3.8
6. Input: 32 batch size, input size (32, 256,64,1)
7. Using model.fit function to train the model
8. 100,277 parameters, 99523 trainable

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think this issue is fixed after I updated the NVIDIA software to the latest version (11.1) and added the most recent ones to the path